# How to read a .p12 file in my web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services

I have a question. I have a web service and I have a ".p12" file that I need to read in my web service for processing a couple of instructions. Reading the ".p12" file  is necessary (The file [certified] allow me create users in my domain [google email service])

Well, In my machine the web service is running fine, but When I publish the web service in the server it doesn't work. I have copied the file (.p12) in the main folder of the web service, in the bin folder too, in the "C" unit in the server, but it doesn't work.

This is the line that read the file (I'm using C#):

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\\nameOfMyFile.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

It shows me one error: **The server can not process the request. ---> Internal error.**

After that,  I tried this:

```
string hpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(".");
hpath = hpath + "\\nameOfMyFile.p12";
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(hpath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

It shows me the same error: **The server can not process the request. ---> Internal error.**

After that, I just write the name of the file:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"nameOfMyFile.p12", "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

It shows me this error: **The server can not process the request. ---> The system can not find the file specified**

So, Do I need to assign one special permission to the file, folder, web service ? What is the best way to read a file like this (.p12)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like it could indeed be a rights issue. Try putting the file in the web site directory and make sure the user you have assigned for anonymous access actually has the rights to read from that directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Honestly I don't Know if this is the best way to do it, but it works in my case.

Add these namespaces:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
```

I use this code:

```
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"file.p12", "password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

And finally I copied my ".p12" file in the "inetsrv" folder of windows.

Answer (score 3):

I other solutions there is a small issue:

1. You have to dump .p12 file in to **"C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\"**.

But if you require .p12 file from application folder like : **"Certificate\xyz.p12"** Then better is to use my solution:

```
path = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Certificates\\CertificatesZoomrideDriver.p12");

 X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path), "Vikas");
```

It's working on domain, local and remote PC.

Vikas Joshi
:):):):):)