# Validate certificate TLS/SSL Server

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ssl

I have been attempting to create an SSL server that loads a certificate from a .crt. I have tried both `X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(@".\Secure\Certificate\" + CertName + ".crt");` and the cert.import, and neither works. On both, I get an issue saying "The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key". And the key is there! My directory:

```
Secure/
    Certificate/
        ZeusHTTP.crt
        ZeusHTTP.csr
        ZeusHTTP.key
    Plugins/
        ...
```

The certs are created with OpenSSL.

Comment: What if you specify absolute path? Side note: I've removed "searched alot" / "thank you" text from your post - try not to add it to your posts as they rarely give any additional details.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I did actually try that. I did get an answer that worked however. Also, I put the I searched a lot because I don't like people who ask without searching and it may have looked like that.

Comment: Your question shows some research already and includes enough details to diagnose the problem. "Have you searched anything" comment is usually made when question shows no effort/details - adding "searched a lot" not going suddenly make question without details a good question nor show effort in searching for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple read of [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromcertfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tells us that you should be using a pkcs7 file that usually has file suffix p7b. You'll need to either convert your OpenSSL cert to this format, or find a utility that can generate one from scratch.

Comment: Certificate with a private key can not be contained in p7b file. Your answer won't solve OP's problem.

Comment: Also the docs are incorrect (this happens sometimes, yes) -- "Any PKCS7 signed file can be used, including an Authenticode signed .pfx file." - Authenticode uses PKCS#7 for signing, but .pfx is not "Authenticode" but PKCS#12.

Answer (score 0):

> The server mode SSL must use a certificate with the associated private key". And the key is there...

As other have stated, they must be in the same file. Here are the steps to do it.

**First**

Copy `ZeusHTTP.crt` to `ZeusHTTP-chain.crt`:

```
cp ZeusHTTP.crt ZeusHTTP-chain.crt
```

**Second**

Open `ZeusHTTP-chain.crt` and ensure it has *all* the intermediates certificates required to validate the server certificate. So you will have 2 or more certificates:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<server certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<intermediate certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<intermediate certificate>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Add certificates as required. For example, if you got a free [Startcom](https://cert.startcom.org/) certificate, then you need to add the `sub.class1.server.ca.pem` intermediate from [StartSSL's Index of Certs](https://www.startssl.com/certs/).

Sending all certificates is required to solve the "which directory" problem in PKI. Its a well known problem in PKI, and essentially it means a client does not know where to go to fetch missing intermediate certificates.

**Third**

Perform the following to generate a PKCS 12 file:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in ZeusHTTP-chain.crt -inkey ZeusHTTP.key -out ZeusHTTP.p12
```

**Fourth**

Finally, install the certificate on IIS as a test.

For your code, I believe you need to load it into a `Certificate2` and not a `Certificate`.

---

Also see [How to read a .p12 file in my web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384377/how-to-read-a-p12-file-in-my-web-service) on Stack Overflow and [how to create x509 certificate and use it in sslstream](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8bcf6b40-619e-4151-9885-22242b7e95b0/how-to-create-x509-certificate-and-use-it-in-sslstream?forum=netfxnetcom) on MSDN.